# Unable to deploy Java Application on Tomcat via Netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

Every time I try to deploy a web application on netbeans, I get the following error:\

> C:\Users{myname}\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045:
>   The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.

The problem is, there are no errors in the apache log!

I have uninstalled my netbeans and installed it afresh, yet still the problem persists. I even downloaded and installed the new netbeans version 8.0, but the problem occurs there too.

I have restarted my laptop countless times, but problem won't go away.

My laptop runs Windows 8.1.

Please, what do I do?

EDIT 1:

I've opened the build-impl.xml file, and here is line 1045

```
   <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Comment: Can you open the build-impl.xml file and look at line 1045? What is it trying to do there?

Comment: Hi Ewald, I've edited my question to include line 1045 in build-impl.xml. Thanks

Comment: So it gets right to the point where it tries to deploy without any errors, but then the container (Tomcat) most probably fails for some reason. I'm guessing you are building a JSF project?

Comment: No, just trying to deploy a basic web application. Created a fresh new web application and clicked "deploy" and I got that. I used to be able to deploy until today.

Comment: Interesting - did you reinstall Tomcat by any chance?

Comment: No. Just reinstalled the entire netbeans, which comes with Tomcat.

Comment: Could you have something that is deployed in Tomcat, but broken, that's stopping it from launching?

Comment: A simpler workaround is to use an embedded server like Jetty/Grizzly where you just run a Java main method and don't need a deployment step. This isn't a direct solution to the question, but it may be useful.

Comment: Hi Ewald, this is a new netbeans installation. There's nothing else running in tomcat.

Comment: Hi user2684301, I need to use tomcat, as that is the server of choice where I work. I can't use Jetty/Grizzly. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there some corruption with my roaming profile. I closed netbeans, deleted the netbeans folders under my roaming profile, restarted my laptop and - presto! Everything's working fine now.

Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am the author of the question, geedubb. The question was I couldn't successfully deploy a web-app on Tomcat and I kept getting a build error, and this persisted after countless netbeans re-installs and laptop shut-downs. The solution to the problem is that I deleted the netbeans folder in my roaming profile, restarted my laptop, and I was able to deploy again. It doesn't get any more complicated than that, I'm afraid.